# Deserialize Unknown Data Type C# and JSON

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

ok so I'm using C# and I'm getting a response from a server, the server can either send a Integer or a String (I'm not able to know ahead of time what data type I will receive) I'm using system.text.json. I'm curious if there is a check or if statement I can utilize to determine what data type I receive and forward it to the appropriate class which contains it defined as either the string or integer declaration that I receive.

i recieve the error: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String
which is fine i understand why i get the error but if i change the class to string/integer i would have to change it every time based on what the response contains from the server

i was trying:

```
if(example.example == int)
    {
      example.ToString()
    }
```

the data contained is always a numerical value as well

the response contains for example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "loot": [],
    "spawns": [],
    "energy": 42,
    "xp": 34965,
    "mana": 1,
    "power": 23
}
```

or

```
{
    "success": true,
    "loot": [],
    "spawns": [],
    "energy": "42",
    "xp": "34965",
    "mana": "1",
    "power": "23"
}
```

sometimes it has a mixture of:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "loot": [],
    "spawns": [],
    "energy": "42",
    "xp": 34965,
    "mana": "1",
    "power": "23"
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data? one response with an int and one with a string, so that we can have a better idea of what we're dealing with here?

Comment: Use  Jsonsoft.Net instead and you will be always happy.

Comment: you mean the newtonsoft one?

Answer (score 0):

It's harder to advise without an example, but you could use [JsonDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsondocument) and then use `.TryGetValue<int>` and then with `<string>` on the node you don't know the type of.